# Unable to remove single lever shower handle

Tags: shower

I'm trying to adjust the temperature monitor to make my shower hotter.  I have a stubborn 11 year old single lever shower handle made by Pioneer that I'm unable to remove, although I've taken the hex screw out.  I've applied WD-40 and a penetrante to lubricate it and also have placed a hot hair drier on it for a long period of time, then I pull but it won't come off.  The handle feels loose but also like there is something holding it in place?  Is there any help out there?

Comment: What model is it?

Comment: I've looked at a number of installation guides for various single handled Pioneer faucets and find they are all held into place by a single hex screw.  A couple of models were noted to have a compression slot (with arrow shaped "grippers") which may account for the problem.  No instruction was given about how tightly these would prevent removal.  One off-the-wall suggestion (based on exp. w/ toilet paper holder): look to see, is there another hex screw still in place?